# Struggling to get to my WP Admin/Login Page

Tags: wordpress

Here's the message I get (address: [www.fisherscovervpark.com/wp-admin](http://www.fisherscovervpark.com/wp-admin))

Warning: require(/home/tc3mr7gt21el/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-dependencies.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/tc3mr7gt21el/public_html/wp-includes/script-loader.php on line 23

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/tc3mr7gt21el/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-dependencies.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php81/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php81/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/tc3mr7gt21el/public_html/wp-includes/script-loader.php:23 Stack trace: #0 /home/tc3mr7gt21el/public_html/wp-settings.php(220): require() #1 /home/tc3mr7gt21el/public_html/wp-config.php(104): require_once('/home/tc3mr7gt2...') #2 /home/tc3mr7gt21el/public_html/wp-loa

Notice: Function is_search was called incorrectly. Conditional query tags do not work before the query is run. Before then, they always return false. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.1.0.) in /home/tc3mr7gt21el/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5835

There has been a critical error on this website.

**I've tried these things:**

https://blogvault.net/cant-access-wordpress-admin-login/
And going into cpanel and disabling each plugin and theme.

I was able to enable WP Errors and thats when I get the long message above. Before I was only getting:

There has been a critical error on this website.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that I also just updated the WP to 6.1 last week.